# Computer Software is Excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Vlookup function, if `col_Index_no` are more than 100 is their any formula or function to take it automatically one after the another? I have to go in each cell cell edit the formula by pressing F2 and put next column no to get the value.

Comment: *"if col_Index_no are more than 100"* ... what does this mean? If the parameter for the function is >100? If  there are more than 100 cells with this formula?

Answer (score 1):

Have a cell with the value needed and refer to that cell from the vlookup then just drag it...

So, `=VLOOKUP(index-val,array,A1,0))` and as you drag `A1` will become `B1` or `A2` if you are working vertically.. etc

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to the below

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$P:$T,COLUMNS($P$1:Q1),FALSE)
```

The columns part, will increment up by one each time you drag it accross,

```
COLUMNS($P$1:Q1)
```

Or if working vertically you can use

```
ROWS($Q$23:Q24)
```